# Como obter aws service com aws-sfk-php-zf2 v 2.0.*?

Tags: php, zend-framework-2, amazon-aws

Eu estava usando aws/aws-sdk-php-zf2 1.2.* e tive de dar update para 2.0.* e agora o AWS SDK é v3.

Antes, eu chamava o serviço com o código:

```
$this->s3 = $serviceLocator->get('aws')->get('s3');
```

Mas agora retorna esse erro:

> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for aws

Não consegui identificar nem encontrar a diferença na documentação de migração.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma forma que funcionou pra mim.

Agora o código está assim:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$this->s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
               'key' => $this->config['aws']['key'],
               'secret' => $this->config['aws']['secret'],
            ),
            'region' => $this->config['aws']['region'],
            'version' => '2006-03-01'
        ));
```